# FFMpeg - Freeze First Frame for X seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to pause/freeze the first frame of the video for 2 seconds before proceeding to the scroll effect. Here's what I have:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -loop 1 -i "temp.jpg" -i "floating.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]fps=fps=30,crop=1280:720:0:'t*(ih-oh)/120',overlay,scale=1280x720,drawtext=fontfile='font.ttf':text='text here':x=20:y=675:fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2,drawtext=fontfile='font.ttf':text='more text':x=w-tw-20:y=670:fontsize=70:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2[out]" -t 10 -map "[out]" -map "0:a" -shortest -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vb 30M -r 30 "video.mp4"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No need for fps filter. Just use `-framerate` input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). overlay accepts two inputs, but you put it in a linear chain. It's working by chance but you will get unexpected results if you use a more complicated filtergraph. Should be something like `'t*(ih-oh)/120'[bg];[bg][2]overlay`. See [filtering introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out using:

```
loop=60:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB
```